# What rules and conditions to add when creating a user group policy for authors

Tags: content-hub, cmp

I have created a new User Group.
The users from this group should have access to only a specific `Content Collection` in `CMP`.
But even before that, I'm  stuck at creating the User Group Policies.
How do I know what `Rules`, `Entities`, `Conditions` to add.
Also,  where can I explore, what each entity means. I could not find this info in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The security model for a user group is `rule-based`. A policy is defined on a user group and each policy can have multiple rules. Each rule consists of conditions and permissions. Rules and conditions are specified for entities of a specific Entity definition. The combination of rules and conditions determines the Entities in scope. The following permissions can be defined on the rule level:

- Core Entity API permissions:

  - Read: allows access to a portal page
  - Create: allows creation of entities related to the entity definition on rule level
  - Update: allows editing entities belonging to the related entity definition
  - Delete: allows editing entities belonging to the related entity definition:
- Asset entity only API permissions:

  - Submit: allows submitting entities for review
  - DirectPublish: allows users to directly approve entities without undergoing the entire approval workflow
  - Approve: allows approving entities under review
  - DownloadOriginal: allows downloading the original rendition file
  - DownloadPreview: allows downloading a preview rendition file
  - Order: allows downloading multiple entities of the related entity definition simultaneously
  - CreatePublicLinks: allows users to create public links for assets
  - ReadPublicLinks: allows users to see the public links of assets
- Asset Only UI permissions:

  - AddVersion: allows users to create versioning on asset entities
  - CreateAnnotations: allows users to create annotations on asset entities
  - ReadAnnotations: allows users to view annotations of other users
  - CreateDraft: allows users to secure original file and create a draft to make necessary modification to a prior approved asset entity
  - ViewNotWatermarked: Per default watermarked renditions are set for non-administrator users. Checking this checkbox allows users to view renditions for instance a preview without watermarking
  - ViewFileHistory: Allows users to view alternative files of asset entities
  - ViewDataHistory: Allows users to view any modification made on each field property of asset entities

You will find more details in the below document for Rules, conditions etc. Also there is an example that they have provided to setup securities.

https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/users/31/content-hub/administration--user-group-policies.html

Comment: The doc was for 3.1 and when I checked for latest versions, it was only until 3.3 and our CH is 4.1+. So, I'm not sure if I'm looking at the right info from 3.3. Secondly, the challenge for me is to understand what entities should be used and what conditions for those entities, when creating a rule. The doc explains permissions, which is fine. Any doc which explains entities & respective conditions in context of UG policies.